# No such column 'IqScore' on entity 'Opportunity'

Tags: soql, opportunity

I am trying to query 'IqScore' field on Opportunity' object, I see this field is available on object level  but when i try to query same from Developer Console query editor or Workbench getting below error.

> No such column 'IqScore' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are
> attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
> the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
> for the appropriate names.

I have cross checked the FLS as well and everything is good? And couldn't find any document reference as well stating this field can't be queried. Is this any reason why this field can't be queried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm), IqScore is accessible to users who have Sales Cloud Einstein license.  The Sales Cloud Einstein license gives users access to scores on all opportunities.  Check more details on Einstein opportunity scoring [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.einstein_sales_opportunity_scoring.htm&type=5).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems to be a difference between a production org and a (developer) sandbox org. In my sandbox org, the Opportunity object has the IqScore field (visible to all profiles), but in Setup 'Einstein Opportunity Scoring' is not visible. I tried to enable Einstein in the sandbox, but so far I have not been succesful.

Even though the field exists according to the Object Manager, I cannot use it, e.g. it is not shown as available for list views.